# TensorFlow - Ignore infinite values when calculating the mean of a tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

This is probably a basic question, but I can't find a solution:

I need to calculate the mean of a tensor **ignoring** any non-finite values.

For example `mean([2.0, 3.0, inf, 5.0])` should return `3.333` and not `inf` nor `2.5`.

I have tried `sess.run(tf.reduce_mean([2.0, 3.0, inf, 5.0]))` but it returns `inf`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a combination of [`is_finite`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/is_finite) and `boolean_mask`.

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([2, 3, float('Inf'), 5])
mymean = tf.reduce_mean(tf.boolean_mask(x, tf.is_finite(x)))

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(mymean)
```

Note that `is_finite` will get rid of `NaN` values as well.

Comment: The key idea is that boolean_mask means "apply mask", not "create mask".  boolean_mask does not return a boolean mask. aha! well then.

Answer (score 8):

The given answer is almost correct. The question asked about ignoring *non-finite* values, the answer only ignores *infinite* values. They are not the same thing, specifically about *nan*.

To actually ignore any non-finite values (including nan), use this slightly simpler line instead:

```
mymean = tf.reduce_mean(tf.boolean_mask(x, tf.is_finite(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer works well for the complete reduction, however, if one wants to use reduce_mean over certain axes only, a more complex approach is required:

```
def reduce_nanmean(tensor, axis=None):
    mask = tf.math.is_finite(tensor)
    numerator = tf.reduce_sum(tf.where(mask, tensor, tf.zeros_like(tensor)), axis=axis)
    denominator = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(mask, dtype=tf.float32), axis=axis)
    return numerator / denominator
```

To get the numerator, the function replaces non-finite numbers (NaN, Inf) with zeros before summing up the numbers in the tensor. To get the denominator (i.e., the number of finite numbers) it sums-up a boolean mask, which masks out the non-finite numbers.